# can't find developer.gserviceaccount for gmail

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I was reading the google documentation about setting up access to post requests to the google server.

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests)

```
{
  "iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.readonly",
  "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
  "exp":1328554385,
  "iat":1328550785
}
```

The iss is the service account name of developer.gserviceaccount.com

However, when I created my service account it came out to be of a format of iam.gserviceaccount.com

How do I use it to post requests and link it to the oauth 2.0 client id?

Thank you

Comment: if the service account email was create on Google developer console it should work.  as for how to post requests using a service account the question is to braod.   post your code and we will try and help you fix it.

Comment: Thank DalmTo. You are right. I have found the solution. Google just replaced their naming of the service accounts and the client IDs. However, the parameters still works. Thanks again for helping!